# limit of the sequence $(x_{n+1})=a^{x_n}$ with $x_1=a$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

We are to find the limit of the sequence $(x_{n+1})=a^{x_n}$, where $x_1=a$ for $a>0$.

Attempt:

Case (1):  $0<a<1$

We have $\frac{1}{a}=(1+ |r_1|)>1$ for some real  $r$.

Hence, $\frac{1}{a^a}=(1+ |r_1|)^a=1+a|r_1|+\frac{a(a-1)}{2}|r_1|^2+...>1$

Evidently, $1+a|r_1|> \frac{1}{a^a}>1$ [$f(x) =1+ax-(1+x)^a \implies f'(x)<0]$. Repeating,  $ 1+a^n|r_1|> \displaystyle\frac{1}{a^{a^{a^{{{.}^{{.}^{.}}}}}}}>1$. But, $\lim|a|^n =1$.

$\therefore$ by Sandwich Theorem we have the result $\lim x_{n+1}=1$

Case (2): $a=1$

Proof is evident.

Case (3): $a>1$

$1> (1/a) \implies 1>(1/a)>(1/a)^a>0$. Clearly, $1/x_n>1/x_{n+1}>0$.

But I want to show that $0$ is indeed an infimum or in some other way, that $(x_n)$ diverges to $\infty$ for $a>1$.

Also, consider checking the other cases.

Answer (score 4):

If the limit $L$ does exist, it is given by the solution of
$$L=a^L\implies L=-\frac{W(-\log (a))}{\log (a)}$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function.).

However, in the real domain, $W(t)$ requires $t \geq -\frac 1e$ that is to say $a \leq e^{\frac{1}{e}}$

Comment: Reminds me of an old Q: If $2=x^{x^{x^{...}}}$ then $x=?$ from a high-school (multiple-choice) contest. Of course $2=x^2$ so $x=\sqrt 2$... ...But I saw that if you replace $2$ with $4$ you get $x^4=4$ so $x=\sqrt 2$ so apparently $2=4.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The contradiction clearly shows the assumption was false: $x^{x^{x^\cdots}} $ cannot equal $2$ for any real  $x$.

Comment: @CiaPan. It DOES equal $2 $ when $x=\sqrt 2.$ The hidden  erroneous assumption is that it can equal $4.$ It cannot be greater than $e,$ which occurs when $x=e^{1/e}. $